# Fancybox iFrame not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox, modal-dialog

I have the equivalent of the following html:

```
<ul>
<a class="iframe" href="/posting/form?id=8"><li>Publish</li></a>
</ul>
```

and the following javascript:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(e){
            $(".iframe").fancybox();
        });
    </script>
```

When I click on the publish button (li tag) nothing shows up. If I link the href to something that does not exist (like www.adfadfasdf.com) the box shows up to say it could not retrieve the information. What am I doing wrong?

Update: There are the following errors when I click the publish button:

```
3
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /posting/form?id=8 jquery.min.js:3
m.error jquery.min.js:3
m.filter jquery.min.js:3
m jquery.min.js:3
c.querySelectorAll.m jquery.min.js:3
f.fn.extend.find jquery.min.js:3
e.fn.e.init jquery.min.js:2
e jquery.min.js:2
$.extend._start jquery.fancybox.js:618
$.extend.open jquery.fancybox.js:204
$.fn.fancybox.run jquery.fancybox.js:1441
f.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3
f.event.add.h.handle.i
```

Comment: have you tried pttting the anchor tag inside the li... does it work then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
<ul>
<li>
<a class="iframe" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="/posting/form?id=8">Publish</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples

Comment: Either way dosen't seem to matter.

Comment: check now we need to add data-fancybox

Comment: It works! Thanks. The placement of the `a` tag doesn't seem to matter though.